# Folland: Convergence in weak topology iff convergence in dual

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence, topological-vector-spaces, weak-topology

I am self-learning real analysis from Folland and got stuck on weak topology convergence. He defines weak topology as follows:

> If $X$ is a normed vector space, the weak topology on $X$ is the weak topology generated by $\{f\,|\, f\in X^{*}\}$.

Then he asserts the following which I am trying to prove:

> If $\langle x_\alpha \rangle$ is a net in $X$, then in the weak topology $\langle x_\alpha \rangle \to x \iff f(x_\alpha) \to f(x) \,\, \forall \, f \in X^*$.

Proof: $\implies$ Let $U$ be any ngh of $f(x)$.

**Q1.** Does this mean $V:=f^{-1}(U)$ is a ngh of $x$ (**in the weak topology?**).

Assuming **Q1**, we have $\exists \, \alpha_0$ such that $x_\alpha \in V \, \, \forall \, \alpha \geq \alpha_0$. Hence $f(x_\alpha) \in U \, \, \forall \, \alpha \geq \alpha_0$. Thus, $f(x_\alpha) \to f(x)$.

**Q2.** How can I go about the reverse implication?

Answer (score 2):

> I don't think I am using $⟨x_α⟩→x$ weakly.

You are. The reason you can choose $\alpha_0$ is that $V$ is a weak-neighbourhood of $x$.

The converse is not too different. Given a neighbourhood $V$ of $x$, by definition of the weak topology there exists $f\in X^*$ and $U\subset \mathbb C$ such that $x\in f^{-1}(U)\subset V$. Since $f(x_\alpha)\to f(x)$, there exists $\alpha_0$ such that $f(x_\alpha)\in U$ for all $\alpha\geq\alpha_0$. Which implies that $x_\alpha\in V$ for all $\alpha\geq\alpha_0$.

Comment: What do you mean by $V$ being a weak-neighborhood of $x$? Folland defines a neighborhood of $x$ as any set $U$ with $x \in \text{int}(U)$

Comment: And how do you define "int"?

Comment: So, we will have $\text{int}(U)$ as the largest open set $V$ contained in $U$ where $V$ is open in the weak topology of $X$. So, $V$ must be a union of sets of the form $\cap_{j=1}^{k} g_{i_j}^{-1}(U_{i_j})$ where $U_{i_j} \subset \mathbb{C}$ is open and $g_{i_j} \in X^*$

Comment: Yes. The point is that $V$ happens to be a neighbourhood in the weak topology. That's why you can say that eventually all elements in the net lie inside it.

Comment: Is this the right reasoning behind $V$ being a weak ngh of $x$: $f(x) \in \text{int}(U) \implies x \in f^{-1}(\text{int}(U)) \subset \text{int}(f^{-1}(U))= \text{int}(V)$ and $f^{-1}(\text{int}(U))$ is open in the weak topology.

Comment: There is no need to talk about interiors because all your sets are open. Since $f(x)\in U$, this means that $x\in f^{-1}(U)$, which is weak-open.

Comment: Folland does not require ngh to be open. So,  $U$ being a ngh of $f(x)$ does not mean $U$ is open. That's why I am using interiors.

Comment: Fair enough. But in this proof you gain nothing by using non-open neighbourhoods, as arbitrary open sets work the same.